# phpmailer send mails via OWN mailserver, missing DKIM

Tags: phpmailer, dkim

i'm using phpmailer V 6.6.0
Here at stackoverflow are a lot of hints and tricks, how to create and use key files for sending DKIM-signed mails.

But my problem is very simple.
I can't remember to provide Thunderbird / Livemail / Outlook whatever with a .key-file.

All i want to do is to use phpmailer sending a mail via my mail server. Like all other EMail-Programs do.

This is my code so far:

```
    $Server = "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.com" ;
    $Username = "mxxxxx" ;
    $Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx" ;
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSendmail();
    // Define the sender
    $mail->Host = $Server; 
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = $Username; 
    $mail->Password = $Password; 
    $mail->Hostname = "@thisdomain.com";
    $mail->MessageID = "<".time()."@thisdomain.com>";
    $mail->XMailer="MyMailer";
    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom($dbset['Sender']);
    $mail->addReplyTo($dbset['Sender']);
    $mail->addAddress($dbset['Receiver']);
    $mail->Subject = "JUST A TEST";
    $mail->isHTML(false);
    $mail->Body = "This is just a test";
    //send the message, check for errors
    $Res = $mail->send(); 
    if (!$Res) die('VERY BAD - Error sending mail!');
    $mail->__destruct();
    unset($mail);
```

Well it works great, beside of the "DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=gmx.net;
s=badeba3b8450; t=1652648844;
bh=x8/D1v6jj+heUcnMHbgz3HeVzmgGNIkhaOk...lots of bytes here..."

What am i doing wrong?
I don't need to set up an own mail server.
My mail server at my provider works great, including the DKIM signature.
Why won't it work with phpmailer?
Signing the Email is not the job of the client, it should be done at the mail server.
Or i'm wrong at this?

Helpless
Mac

Comment: Did you try following [the DKIM signing example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/DKIM_sign.phps)? Note the key setup script in the same folder as that too.

Comment: No i did not. Because all these examples require an OWN Mailserver.
My Problem is, how to send an email, like it would be sent via Outlook, Thunderbird, whatever.
None of these programs require to upload any key file.
Because the validation / DKIM entry will be done be the mail server you're connecting to. And i provide all informations, that i would use for Outlook, etc.
So my personal mailserver is  (or at least should) be used.
Let's shrink the question: "How can i use phpmailer, to connect and send an email like Outlook or Thunderbird would do?"

Comment: In that case all you need is the basic example from the PHPMailer readme. It does exactly what you ask, exactly as Outlook and Thunderbird do. You can do DKIM signing at whatever point you like. Doing it on the server is super convenient, but if your server doesn’t do it, signing with the client is fine (and is why PHPMailer supports it), though note that Outlook and Thunderbird don’t offer that. Your error checking code isn’t good. It will tell you it failed, but not why – see the examples for how to do it better.

Comment: @Synchro: Thanks for the help, My main mistake was to set
     <code>$mail->isSendmail();</code>
instead of 
     <code>$mail->isSMTP();</code> .
Works perfect now! Thank you.